# Motion eye webcam and micro doesn't work

Tags: 10.04, webcam, sony

I'm having problems with my motion eye webcam and my microphone. it doesnt work on Ubuntu... i already tested it with cheese, empathy and pidgin, but ubuntu doesnt recognize it.

My system:

- sony vaio vgn fz21s
- RAM: 2GB
- graphics: nvidia geforce 8600m gs
- cpu: intel centrino duo 2.2 ghz
- harddrive: 320 gb

Comment: We need hardware information, please add some to your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Answer (score 1):

we need more information about your hardware in order to understand exactly what it is and how it's failing to work, you can follow the instructions in the question here:

[I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into)

It's likely at this stage that the makers of your webcam have not provided any documentation or drivers to get your hardware working. Please consider asking the manufacturer for support in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The fix found at https://bitbucket.org/ahixon/r5u87x

Enter the code, 1 command at a time, into a terminal window.

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev libusb-dev build-essential gcc automake mercurial
hg clone http://bitbucket.org/ahixon/r5u87x/
cd r5u87x
make
sudo make install
sudo r5u87x-loader --reload
```

The loader will automatically be run on boot when it detects your webcam.

Comment: You have posted the same answer on two other questions. Are they (the questions) duplicates of each other in your opinion? We discourage against posting duplicate answers, so I suggest if you run into duplicate questions, that you flag them as such.

Comment: They were similar questions, which are looking for the same answer. I'll post a link next time. Sorry